# How to download a Google Cloud Compute Engine VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a GCE VM instance and I would like to download it so I can do some development using VirtualBox.

There seems to be a lot of information on how to upload VMs to Google Cloud, but there is nothing on how I can download it.

How can I download the GCE VM instance from Google Cloud?

Answer (score 9):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image) explains this; you'd have to [create an image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#create_image) from the boot disk first, [export it to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image#exporting_an_image_with_a_single_command) as a `tar.gz`, and from there on, [download it from Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects) into your local machine, decompress it, and use it as you wish.

As an example, and a quick step-by-step guide using the **CLI**:

1. **Create an image from the boot disk** with [`gcloud compute images
   create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/create):

   ```
   gcloud compute images create my-image \
     --source-disk my-disk \
     --source-disk-zone zone
   ```

   Replace `my-image` with the name you want to give to the image,
   `my-disk` with the name of the boot disk and `zone` with the name of
   the zone the disk is located at, i.e `us-central1-a`.
2. **Export it to Cloud Storage** with [`gcloud compute images export`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/export):

   If you don't have a Cloud Storage bucket, you'd indeed, need to [create one](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets) first, otherwise, skip this part. By using the CLI you can create a bucket with [`gsutil mb`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mb), i.e `gsutil mb gs://my-bucket/`. Replace `my-bucket` with the name you desire to give it. Be aware that the name has a single namespace, so you are not allowed to create a bucket with a name already in use by another user.

   ```
   gcloud compute images export \
       --destination-uri gs://my-bucket/my-image-file.tar.gz \
       --image my-image
   ```

   Replace `my-bucket` with the name of the Cloud Storage bucket you
   want to export it to, `my-image-file` with the name of the file
   containing the image and `my-image` with the name of the image you
   previously created.

   You might be prompted to enable the *Cloud Build API* and to add
   some permissions to it at this point - enter `y` as it's a [necessary
   step](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image#enable-cloud-build) for the export tool.
3. Once the image has finished uploading to Cloud Storage, **download it
   to your local machine** with [`gsutil cp`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp):

   ```
   gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/my-image-file.tar.gz /local/path/to/file
   ```

   Replace `my-bucket` with the name of the bucket you previously specified
   , `my-image-file` with the name you gave to the file
   containing the image, and `/local/path/to/file` with the local path
   you wish it to be download to.